# windows 8 set as desktop background

Tags: background, wallpaper

I'm writing a small program to change desktop background with one or two mouse clicks..

I know that I can right click on any Image file and set it as Desktop Background..

And exactly there is where the problem starts. I cant find the proper entry in any dll which would have the entry Set As Desktop Background or even New Desktop Background.

I know how I can create those in registry, but I don't want to edit registry for this, rather I would like to have it set right in my Tiny Program so with two clicks I would get control over all image files on my Computer to display them as Desktop Background. and this from any folder or even from any connected drive, without to have to return to Personalization menu.

If anyone of you knows where I can find the entry's of above mentioned Context menu Strings, so I would be very thankful.

This is just for personal use, neither to sell or give away..

Thank you Chris

P.S. Please forgive me my bad English, I'm from a non English speaking European country.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at, for example, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations.jpg\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper\Command

You'll notice that it has the DelegateExecute member set. This means that windows will attempt to use the IExecuteCommand interface in the specified DLL. Reading up on what that does on MSDN, and attempting to emulate explorer, I came up with this, which works.

I'm not sure why that Sleep() is needed though, I'd love if anyone could elaborate on that.

```
void SetWallpaper(LPCWSTR path)
{
    const GUID CLSID_SetWallpaper = { 0xFF609CC7, 0xD34D, 0x4049, { 0xA1, 0xAA, 0x22, 0x93, 0x51, 0x7F, 0xFC, 0xC6 } };
    HRESULT hr;
    IExecuteCommand *executeCommand = nullptr;
    IObjectWithSelection *objectWithSelection = nullptr;
    IShellItemArray *shellItemArray = nullptr;
    IShellFolder *rootFolder = nullptr;
    LPITEMIDLIST idlist = nullptr;

    // Initalize COM, probably shouldn't be done in this function
    hr = CoInitialize(nullptr);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the IExecuteCommand interface of the DLL
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SetWallpaper, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IExecuteCommand, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&executeCommand));

        // Get the IObjectWithSelection interface
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = executeCommand->QueryInterface(IID_IObjectWithSelection, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&objectWithSelection));
        }

        //
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&rootFolder);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = rootFolder->ParseDisplayName(nullptr, nullptr, (LPWSTR)path, nullptr, &idlist, NULL);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDLists(1, (LPCITEMIDLIST*)&idlist, &shellItemArray);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = objectWithSelection->SetSelection(shellItemArray);
        }

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = executeCommand->Execute();
        }

        // There is probably some event, or something to wait for here, but we
        // need to wait and relinquish control of the CPU, or the wallpaper won't
        // change.
        Sleep(2000);

        // Release interfaces and memory
        if (idlist)
        {
            CoTaskMemFree(idlist);
        }
        if (executeCommand)
        {
            executeCommand->Release();
        }
        if (objectWithSelection)
        {
            objectWithSelection->Release();
        }
        if (shellItemArray)
        {
            shellItemArray->Release();
        }
        if (rootFolder)
        {
            rootFolder->Release();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}
```

Edit: After doing some more research on this, for my own sake, I realized that stobject.dll actually just uses the IDesktopWallpaper interface; which is part of CLSID_DesktopWallpaper

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706946(v=vs.85).aspx